# Prove $2^n \in \mathcal{O}(n!)$

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Can someone help me with this?  So far I have:

$2^n < c * n!$ for all $n \ge k$, where $c > 0$ and $k > 0$

$\frac {(2^n)}{n!} < c$ for all $n \ge k$

I'm not sure where to proceed.

Comment: $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2^n}{n!}=e^2.$$

Comment: Hint: $2^n = 2 \cdot 2 \cdots 2$ with $n$ $2$s, $n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdots n$ with $n$ terms.

Comment: $n!=1*2*3*4...*n\gt 1*2*2*(2*2)*...*2$

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 1):

If $n\ge3$,$$\frac{2^n}{n!}=\frac{8\cdot 2^{n-3}}{6\prod_{k=4}^nk}\le\frac{2^n}{6\cdot 4^{n-3}}=\frac{32}{3}2^{-n}\in o(1).$$